# Use subprocess.call for command with a pipe redirection

Tags: python, subprocess

Having read other answers on here, I know that `shell=True` is frowned upon, but I am having trouble with a command (more accurately a pair of commands?) with a pipe redirect.

This works:

```
subprocess.call('echo "Test" | mail -s "Test" test@gmail.com', shell=True)
```

but this does not:

```
subprocess.call(["echo", "Test", "|", "mail", "-s", "'Test'", test@gmail.com"]))
```

Any suggestions on how to make the second one work?

Comment: Thanks - had found a similar topic & was coming back to close.

Comment: @mu 無 do you need to post that as an answer so that I can accept it & close the topic?

Comment: Ok, Have posted that as an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below to get a piped output like this:

```
echo "Test" | mail -s "Test" test@gmail.com'
```

Basically, create multiple [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) objects, specify one's stdout as a PIPE, and feed this as an stdin to the other object:

```
p1 = Popen(["echo", "Test"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["mail", "-s", "Test", "test@gmail.com"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

You can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856655/1860929) for more info.