# How to execute this command in using python subprocess modude

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I execute this command using python's subProcess module

```
gunzip --name /tmp/file.gz > /home/aaaa/
```

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856583/how-do-i-pipe-a-subprocess-call-in-python-to-a-text-file) would be a more appropriate dupe target. The problem here is more along the usage of the `>` to output to file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subprocess` and redirect your output to a file:

```
import subprocess
output_file = open("/home/aaaa/myoutput", "w")
subprocess.call(["gunzip", "--name",  "/tmp/file.gz"], stdout=output_file)
```