# python - i can't get the same result from os.system in subprocess

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

i want to convert from os.system into subprocess the following

```
os.system("egrep 'Invalid user' /home/bits/Desktop/Assessment/auth.log | cut -d ' ' -f 11 >tempfile.txt ")
```

it works but when i write the same statement using subprocess it will create an empty file , does some1 know why and how to resolve that ? thx

```
a1=subprocess.Popen(["egrep \"Invalid users\" /home/bits/Desktop/Assessment/auth.log"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)   ### instead of /home/bits/Desktop/Assessment/auth.log please modify with your full path of auth.log
a2=subprocess.Popen(["cut -d \" \" -f 11 > /home/bits/Desktop/Assessment/rezolvare/tempfile.txt"],shell=True,stdin=a1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: You should redirect stdout to file using `stdout` parameter. Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856583/how-do-i-pipe-a-subprocess-call-to-a-text-file

Comment: i modified it but i has the same result:an empty file a2=subprocess.Popen(["cut -d \" \" -f 11 "],shell=True,stdin=a1.stdout,stdout=open_file)

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the output file as `stdout`:

```
with open("/home/bits/Desktop/Assessment/rezolvare/tempfile.txt", "wb") as output:
    a1 = subprocess.Popen(["egrep",  "Invalid users", "/home/bits/Desktop/Assessment/auth.log"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    a2 = subprocess.Popen(["cut", "-d", " ", "-f", "11"], stdin=a1.stdout, stdout=output)
```

writing in pure python is even simpler:

```
with open("/home/bits/Desktop/Assessment/auth.log") as lines:
    with open("/home/bits/Desktop/Assessment/rezolvare/tempfile.txt", "wb") as output:
        for line in lines:
            if "Invalid users" in line:
                output.write(line.split(" ")[10] + "\n")
```

Comment: Daniel , i tried the first and the second but i think i have a problem here , i get an empty file everytime i run it ? with os.system works or with bash but the way u got it does not work , maybe i have a problem here , do u have the answer to it ?thx