# How to execute a Python CLI module and get the output periodically

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-interface

I am developing a GUI interface for a Python module (running in CLI), that when executed was the output bellow:

```
Progress:  50%|███████████████                | 45/45 [time,  info]
Message 1
Message 2
Progress: 100%|███████████████████████████████| 45/45 [time,  info]
Finished!
```

I intend to execute this as a `subprocess` and get the output, parse the perceptual to a process bar and the "Messages" to a log.

How I do that? Is it possible with `subprocess` get the output of a CLI software periodically (or each new entry) without show the terminal?

To execute it now, I am using `subprocess.call('shell command', shell=True)`. So it is really a shell command (that at the end load and run a python module), but this give the output in the terminal.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to write to a file in python? Check out the docs for Input and Output: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Yes, write a file, is almost the same in each language. But how this could help me? I intend to not change the CLI software (I can, but prefer also keep it as a possible interface). Just intend to run the GUI as a layer between the ~not experient~ user and the CLI.

Comment: Something as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856583/how-do-i-pipe-a-subprocess-call-to-a-text-file, I realize.
But how to process this output file to update the GUI, by a timer? (appear not pythonized)